# Unexpected "Connection timed out: proxy connect" lines in Apache error.log

Tags: proxy, apache-1.3

I see some unexpected lines in my Apache (1.3!) error.log.  What is happening here?  My isp has complained in the past about proxying attempts... how do I check for them?

```
[Sun Apr  4 16:43:32 2010] [error] [client 60.173.11.34] (110)Connection timed out: proxy   connect to 61.132.221.146 port 80 failed
[Sun Apr  4 16:44:11 2010] [error] [client 60.173.11.34] (110)Connection timed out: proxy connect to 61.132.221.146 port 80 failed
[Sun Apr  4 16:45:34 2010] [error] [client 79.2.28.220] (110)Connection timed out: proxy connect to 203.212.171.170 port 80 failed
```

Never, mind, I think this is the issue:

```
     <Directory proxy:*>
         Order deny,allow
-        Allow from all
-        #Allow from mysite.net
+        #Allow from all
+        Allow from mysite.net
     </Directory>
```

Wtf was I thinking!  Allow from all!  Can someone confirm my moronity!?